# ManyToMany relationship entries are not being displayed in Spring REST

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-data

I have two classes: `MenuItem.java` and `Tag.java`. I am using the Hibernate implementation of JPA, and using `PagingAndSortingRepository`. After creating a bunch of dummy MenuItems and Tags, these are displayed in my local database and can be accessed with either: localhost:8080/api/menuItems or localhost:8080/api/tags. Additionally, as described by my annotations in the files below, there exists a `ManyToMany` relationship between these two objects, and a Menu_Items_Tags table with the appropriate entries is also created in my database without any issue.

The problem I run into is that every time I attempt to access a given menu item's list of tags via: localhost:8080/api/menuItems/1/tags for example, I receive a `500 error` and additionally have a repeating error code like this:

`: HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@726b0462<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1877641821 wrapping Result set representing update count of 6>`

Is there something I am doing wrong in either trying to request the Tags of a MenuItem or am I incorrectly setting up my @ManyToMany relationship?

`MenuItem.java:`

```
@Data
@Entity
public class MenuItem implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1132661429342356177L;

public MenuItem() {
}

public MenuItem(String name, Double price, Integer inventory, String description, Set<Tag> tags) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.inventory = inventory;
    this.description = description;
    this.tags = tags;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;

@Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
private Double price;

@Column(name = "inventory", nullable = false)
private Integer inventory;

@Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
private String description;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "menuItem")
private Set<Order> orders;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="menu_item_tags",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "menu_item_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Tag> tags;

}
```

`Tag.java:`

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Tag implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1132661429342356176L;

public Tag() {
}

public Tag(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", unique = true)
private String name;

//    @JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
@JsonBackReference
private Set<MenuItem> menuItems;
}
```

Comment: have you debugged the Getters and enabled debugging for Hibernate? please do so to see what Hibernate is really doing (enable hibernate's "show_sql" too to see the queries in the log)

Comment: I did as you recommended, and now I see an almost infinite list of hibernate SELECT queries - I assume there is some unwanted recursion occurring in between the parent and child entities (menuItems and Tags).

 I assumed that putting the `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` annotations would resolve this issue but it does not seem to be working.